# Como printar texto digitado em uma GUI do tkinter no console?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu queria criar um texto em uma janela e, apertando um botão, o meu texto aparecer no console. O meu código é esse:

```
from tkinter import *
class janela:
    def __init__ (self, janela):
        self.frame=Frame()
        self.frame.config(height=300,width=300,bg='black')
        self.frame.pack()
        janela.config(bg='black')
        janela.title('TITULO')

        text1 = Text (self.frame, width=20, height=5)
        text1.pack()
        confirm = Button (self.frame, text='Confirmar texto', fg='red', command=
                            lambda: print(text1))
        confirm.pack()
            
            
jan1 = Tk()
janela(jan1)
jan1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez quase tudo certo, mas faltou notar que o texto é um *atributo* do seu frame, não o frame em si. Note que, da forma como está, seu programa está printando o nome do objeto (`!frame.!text`). Para obter o texto, você precisa adicionar o método `get`. Abaixo código com a correção:

```py
from tkinter import *
class janela:
    def __init__ (self, janela):
        self.frame=Frame()
        self.frame.config(height=300,width=300,bg='black')
        self.frame.pack()
        janela.config(bg='black')
        janela.title('TITULO')

        text1 = Text(self.frame, width=20, height=5)
        text1.pack()
        confirm = Button (self.frame, text='Confirmar texto', fg='red', command=
                            lambda: print(text1.get(1.0, "end-1c")))
        confirm.pack()
            
            
jan1 = Tk()
janela(jan1)
jan1.mainloop()
```